# Error: <path> attribute d: Expected arc flag ('0' or '1')

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I have looked for possible solutions but nothing worked for me.

Problem is when I try to update the data and the pie chart accordingly, the transition does not work and prints error, mentioned in the topic,  more than once. I am kinda new to JS, so I am looking for some help.

Code:

```
    var pie = d3.pie();

    var pathArc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(200)
        .outerRadius(250);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var t = d3.transition()
        .duration(500);

    var path = piesvg.selectAll("path")
        .data(pie(gdp_values));

    path.exit()
        .transition(t)
        .remove();

    path.transition(t)
        .attr("d",function (d) {
            return pathArc(d);
        })
        .attr("fill",function(d, i){return color(i);});

    path.enter()
        .append("path")
        .transition(t)
        .attr("d",pathArc)
        .attr("fill",function(d, i){return color(i);});
```

Initial dataset(gdp_values);

```
[407500000000, 417300000000, 439800000000, 680900000000, 980900000000, 1160000000000, 1727000000000, 2249000000000, 2389000000000, 3074000000000]
```

It does work when data changed to the another similar data, however when changes to the data as follows, transitions doesnot work and throws the same error 40 times.

```
[7714000000, 123900000000, 846200000000]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invert the order of your selections: the enter selection should come before the update selection:

```
path.enter()
    .append("path")
    .transition(t)
    .attr("d", pathArc)
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
    });

path.transition(t)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        return pathArc(d);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
    });
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var piesvg = d3.select("svg").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(250,250)")

var gdp_values = [407500000000, 417300000000, 439800000000, 680900000000, 980900000000, 1160000000000, 1727000000000, 2249000000000, 2389000000000, 3074000000000];

var gdp_values2 = [7714000000, 123900000000, 846200000000];

var pie = d3.pie();

var pathArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(200)
  .outerRadius(250);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var t = d3.transition()
  .duration(500);

update(gdp_values)

setTimeout(function() {
  update(gdp_values2);
}, 1000)

function update(data) {

  var path = piesvg.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(data));

  path.exit()
    .transition(t)
    .remove();

  path.enter()
    .append("path")
    .transition(t)
    .attr("d", pathArc)
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(i);
    });

  path.transition(t)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return pathArc(d);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(i);
    });



}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
```

Comment: It didn't work but I used the function called `arcTween` on this link instead of directly using the `pathArc`. It worked then, however the animation was not that satisfying. @Gerardo Furtado

Comment: What do you mean by *"it didn't work"*? Did you see my snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when making data updates to a chart. Solution in my case was to prevent drawing of the chart during the time the data was loading. Guessing the arcTween code doesn't handle data changes gracefully.